# Update View when a new day comes / SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need to update my Button Color automatically if a new day comes. ( If the button was pressed, for example, yesterday, it was purple, today color of the button must be green ) **I need it to work while I am using my app.**

Here is my Button View Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ButtonView: View {
    
    @Binding var streak: Int
    @State private var lastUserDate: Date?
    
    private var canUserPress: Bool {
        let lastUserDate = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "lastUserDate")
        if let canUserPress = lastUserDate as? Date {
            print(!Calendar.current.isDateInToday(canUserPress))
            return !Calendar.current.isDateInToday(canUserPress)
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
    private var buttonColor: LinearGradient {
        return canUserPress ?
        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.black, Color.green]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing) :
        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.black, Color.purple]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
        
    }

    var body: some View {
            Button {
                if canUserPress {
                    lastUserDate = Date()
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(lastUserDate, forKey: "lastUserDate")
                    streak += 1
                }
            } label: {
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(buttonColor)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    
                    Text("Add!")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                
            }
    }
}

struct ButtonView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ButtonView(streak: .constant(0))
    }
}
```

Comment: Use AppStorage instead of UserDefaults

Comment: But how can I use AppStorage with dates?

Answer (score 0):

`@AppStorage` has built in capabilities to trigger `View` updates in SwiftUI.

To use `AppStorage` with just about any type all your have to do is make sure it conforms to `RawRepresentable` with `RawValue == String`, `timeIntervalSince1970` is the simplest way with `Date`.

```
extension Date: RawRepresentable{
    public var rawValue: String {
        self.timeIntervalSince1970.description
    }
    
    public init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let interval = TimeInterval(rawValue) else {
            return nil
        }
        self = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: interval)
    }
}
```

Then you can use

```
@AppStorage("lastUserDate") var date: Date = Date()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a timer that fires at the next midnight, e.g.

```
var timerForNextMidnight: Timer {
    // calculate the time interval til next midnight or create a date for next midnight
    // create a timer that fires after the interval or on the date.
}

.onReceive(timerForNextMidnight) { timer in
    // update state that button uses
}
```

Note you also need to use this calendar in the timer fire date calculation, so the timer is recreated if the user changes their calendar in Settings while the app is running.

```
@Environment(\.calendar) var calendar
```

Would you like help in calculating the time interval between now and next midnight? [SwiftDate](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate) might help with that.